# Unique factorization in 3-sphere coordinate ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

For $n\geqslant 1$ define $$A_n=\mathbb{C}[X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n]\Bigg/\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}X^2_i-1\right).$$

I would like to prove that $A_3$ is a unique factorization domain.

For $A_2$ it is not true because we can show that the factorization is not always unique. In general, $A_n$ is a Noetherian integral domain, so it suffices to prove that every irreducible element of $A_3$ is also a prime. There is an additional lemma which might be helpful: If $A$ is a Noetherian domain and $\pi$ its prime element, therefore $A[X]/(\pi X-1)$ being UFD implies that $A$ is UFD.

Any directions would be helpful. References?

Comment: You can use Grothendieck's Theorem http://math.stackexchange.com/a/381999/84157 (plus the Jacobian criterion (regular local rings are UFDs) to say it is locally UFD at primes of height at most $3$) to show that it is locally UFD. But I have no idea if it is globally UFD or not.